# Kotlin Koans: Named arguments solution

Tags: kotlin, collections

I'm practising Kotlin on [Kotlin Koans](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/koans.html) and am up to the [Named Arguments](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Named%20arguments/Task.kt) question.

**Named arguments**

> Default and named arguments help to minimize the number of overloads
>   and improve the readability of the function invocation. The library
>   function joinToString is declared with default values for parameters:

```
fun joinToString(
    separator: String = ", ",
    prefix: String = "",
    postfix: String = "",
    /* ... */
): String
```

> It can be called on a collection of Strings. Specifying only two
>   arguments make the function joinOptions() return the list in a JSON
>   format (e.g., "[a, b, c]")

The answer:

```
fun joinOptions(options: Collection<String>) = options.joinToString(prefix = "[", postfix = "]")
```

adds "[" to the start and "]" to the end of the collection. However I tried printing the collection with and without `joinOptions()`, and they both have the same outcome:

```
val collection: Collection<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3)
fun joinNumbers(numbers: Collection<Int>) = numbers.joinToString(prefix = "[[", postfix = "]")
println(collection) // prints [1, 2, 3]
println(joinNumbers((collection))) // prints [1, 2, 3]
```

So I'm just curious if I'm missing something? - what were they going for in this question?

Comment: Did it really print out the second time with only one `[` while your prefix is `[[`?

Comment: My mistake that should be only one `[`. I was just testing to see if prefix was working by adding another one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`println(collection)` calls the `toString()` method on the `Collection` object, and some collections will print their contents in the following format:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

which indeed is equivalent to calling

```
collection.joinToString(prefix = "[", delimiter = ", ", postfix = "]")
```

You cannot modify this behavior though, so if, for instance, you wanted to print every element in the collection on its own line you'd have to write your own implementation of `toString()`. This is where `joinToString()` comes handy, you can just do

```
collection.joinToString(delimiter = "\n")
```

Note that you don't need to pass arguments for `prefix` or `postfix` cause the default values fit your use case.

The Koans example could probably be less confusing, but it does the job of illustrating the usage of named arguments and default values.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is like that:

```
fun joinOptions(options: Collection<String>) = options.joinToString(
    prefix = "[",
    separator = ", ",
    postfix = "]"
)
```